# Store data into localStorage session in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, local-storage

I have this API controller receive data from URL and store it into the database, I would like to store it into the local storage and redirect me to another page. In my code when I remove the part of redirecting, the data is stored into local storage and database successfully but I need both of the processes, storing to local storage and redirect me to another page.

```php
public function storePayment(Request $request)
{
    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $payment->save();

    return "<script>

    localStorage.setItem('user_id', JSON.stringify($user_id));
    localStorage.setItem('request_id', {$payment->request_id});
    localStorage.setItem('price', {$payment->price});
    localStorage.setItem('user_phone', {$payment->user_phone});

    window.location.href = 'https://my-app.com/app/payment';

  </script>";

}
```

Comment: `in my code when I remove the part of redirecting the data store into local storage and database` this part is unclear

Comment: are you sure $user_id and $payment has values?

Comment: please add the code where you are getting the data from localStorage

Comment: yes I am sure they have values .

Comment: add in your question the part of your code where you are trying to `get` the value from localStorage, after you redirect

Comment: I'm sorry, but this approach appears to be absurd; why not use sessions? There is absolutely no reason to store something client-side.

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes in your php variables? Ex: localStorage.setItem('user_phone', '{$payment->user_phone}');